# Do all methods have to return a meaningful value?

Tags: ruby

Here's a snippet of code from the pickaxe book:

```
def count_frequency(word_list) counts = Hash.new(0)
  for word in word_list
    counts[word] += 1
  end
  counts
end
```

The `counts` at the end sets the return value of the method. The value returned is the value of the last calculation.

However, are there not cases where we don't care what the return value of a method is? For example, I have a pair of nested `each` loops that draw a checkerboard to console. The values of the calculations are fairly meaningless outside the method. I just want a checkerboard drawn.

Is it bad to leave the return value up to circumstance, or should I always be trying to explicitly design methods that return meaningful values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to care about the return value if that method is not used as such with a certain expected value. Nothing to worry about.

But for your `counts` example, returning that value is the whole point of the method. If the method didn't return that value, then it is meaningless, and you definitely need that `counts` at the end.

There are some cases when the return value is not the main purpose of the method but you still want to return a certain value. One such case is when the method is intended to be used in a jQuery-style method chain like this:

```
some_object.do_this(args).do_that(args).then_do_this
```

In such case, it is important that you return the receiver. This happens in certain libraries or frameworks, but unless you specifically intent it to be used that way, you don't necessarily have to do it that way.

Comment: When in doubt, return `self`.

Answer (score 1):

## No.

In Ruby, every expression returns a value, even if it is just `nil`. Not just methods; every line you write. In the case of methods, the value returned is the last value evaluated before it exits. The meaning of that value is up to you. If you document that the method has no return value, then even though it does return a value it is undefined; not part of the API and the caller would be wise not to make use of it.

For example, even `nil` can have proper meaning if you document it; it is often used to signal that a resource could not be found. However, if a method's sole purpose is to perform a side effect like writing to a file, it will probably something that has no real meaning; `puts` returns `nil.`

Answer (score 1):

No, the return value is not necessary when the method isn't supposed to return a meaningful value, just like most other programming languages.

In fact, one of the most common methods, `puts`, returns `nil`.

```
#puts "hello"
hello
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

*Theoretically*, if you document clearly that the return value is meaningless, then you could just incidentally return whatever the last expression in the method happens to evaluate to.

*Practically*, however, nobody reads documentation, so, if your method *does* return something, then people *will* come to depend on it. Also, depending on what exactly it is that you are "accidentally" returning, you might leak private internal implementation details of your method or you might even break encapsulation of your object by e.g. returning the value of a private instance variable.

Take the `defined?` unary prefix operator, for example. It is specified as returning either a trueish or a falseish value. However, on MRI, it does not just return any trueish value, it actually returns a `String` describing the kind of expression that is asked about (e.g. `'local-variable'`, `'method'`, etc.) And people have become so dependent on this return value that all other Ruby implementations just *have* to mimic it, even though it is nowhere documented. Now, it turns out that for MRI this information is trivially available, but for JRuby it is not, and keeping this information around incurs a performance penalty.

The E programming language is a purely expression-based language like Ruby or Lisp. Everything is an expression, there are no statements. Everything returns a value. However, unlike those other languages, the implicit return value of a subroutine is not the value of the last expression evaluated inside the subroutine, it is `nil`. You *must* explicitly `return` a value if you want to return something meaningful. That is because the creator of E believes that it is too dangerous to accidentally return something you didn't want. (E is explicitly designed for security, safety, integrity and reliability.)

Comment: The break between theory and practice is a particularly important point given the sugary nature of Ruby. For whatever reason, I've always been somewhat troubled by implicit returns, and the reasons you've cited are precisely why. Vielen Dank. Gruesse aus Kalifornien.